# mpiexec won't run mpi4py script when two hosts are utilized in an MPI cluster established through LAN

Tags: python, ssh, mpi, hosting

So I have this other desktop PC, that serves as my server, `primesystem` and a laptop as my client, `zerosystem` that is connected to it. They both serve as my `ssh-server` and `ssh-client` respectively, and is connected through an ethernet (not crossover) cable.

I both followed the instructions stated in these tutorials:
[Running an MPI Cluster within a LAN](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/) and [Setting Up an MPICH2 Cluster in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster), only that I would like to use the MPI implementation of `python`, so I instead used `mpi4py` to test if both PC could utilize MPI.

I set up a directory `/cloud` in `primesystem` that shall be shared in my network, and this is mounted in my `zerosystem`, as instructed by the first tutorial (so I could also work in either both systems without the need to log-in through `ssh`).

In the server or `primesystem`, if I run the sample helloworld script, it works fine:

```
one@primesystem:/cloud$ mpirun -np 5 -hosts primesystem python -m mpi4py helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on primesystem.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on primesystem.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on primesystem.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on primesystem.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on primesystem.
```

Same goes if I run it through the host `zerosystem` (but it should be noted there's a noticeable delay in execution due to utilizing external CPU from `zerosystem`):

```
one@primesystem:/cloud$ mpirun -np 5 -hosts zerosystem python -m mpi4py helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on zerosystem.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on zerosystem.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on zerosystem.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on zerosystem.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on zerosystem.
```

But if I utilized the two hosts, it doesn't seem to respond at all:

```
one@primesystem:/cloud$ mpirun -np 5 -hosts primesystem,zerosystem python -m mpi4py helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on primesystem.
```

(If I interchanged the order of hosts, `zerosystem` being first, no Hello World response is shown)

I tried entering the lists of hosts in a `.mpi-config` file and their respective processes to spawn, then utilizing the `-f` parameter instead of `-hosts`

```
zerosystem:4
primesystem:2
```

but it still gets the same response, and after several seconds or minute, this is the error output:

```
one@primesystem:/cloud$ mpirun -np 6 -f .mpi-config python -m mpi4py helloworld
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 23329 RUNNING AT primesystem
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
[proxy:0:1@zerosystem] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:886): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:1@zerosystem] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:1@zerosystem] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@primesystem] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@primesystem] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@primesystem] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:218): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@primesystem] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:336): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Why is this? Any ideas?